# user authentication using sessions causes redirect loop

Tags: php

I am trying to make a authentication script, to redirect logged/unlogged users to proper page but its causing redirect loop. I have two page index.php which has the login form and the mobile.php which has the contents for valid users. For authentication i have this code on the very first lines of index.php

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
    header("location: mobile.php");
    exit();
}
```

and the very first lines of mobile.php is

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){ 
    header("location: index.php"); 
}
```

But I dont know why its causing a redirect loop.
Here are some screenshots.
Thanks for your time.
[image: here you can see the redirects]
[image: here are the headers being sent]

Here are some codes from index.php, these codes lines are followed by the form for login. In the validate function all I do is check if the username and password is valid, if yes then i regenerate session id, and set session variable username and userid. and return true.

```
if(isset($username) && isset($password)){
    $username = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $username);  
    $password = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $password);
    $returnmsg = validate($username,$password);
    if($returnmsg===true){
        // header("location: mobile.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $returnmsg = 'Invalid username or password.';
    }           
}
```

Comment: Add an `exit();` after redirect in index.php. Also dump out the session variable without redirect in index.php

Comment: Works fine for me! It has to be in other code lines

Comment: after clearing all cookies and restarting the browser i used var_dump($_SESSION); right after session_start(); the result is empty array. So the index page should not redirect and continue, but it does redirect, Why?

Comment: @rkrara You have to show us more code!

Comment: Is there any other places you used header() within index.php? Or included a page that uses header()? From the symptom it seems like you might have accidentally placed the block of code (from mobile.php) inside index.php or somehow being executed. Can you place an echo right before header() in mobile.php?

Comment: @Rizier123  yes, on the index page later when the user fills in the login form, the data are posted to the same page and I use those to check if the login information are correct, if yes i set the sessions variables and redirect to mobile.php using header.

Comment: @rkrara Then show us this code!

Comment: @Rizier123 I just edited my post to include the codes executed to check valid users and set sessions variables for them.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I resolved it. It was caused by the call for sql class file, where I had also put the same code as on top of mobile.php to protect the file from unauthorized access via browser address bar. But now can anybody say, how do I protect this file from all kind of users, none is supposed to view it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Allways exit after location header.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){ 
   header("location: index.php"); 
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Does it make any difference, as far as I know as sooon come as it comes to header, it redirects. Thanks.

Comment: But it's still possible to try to output something. So doing an exit is just to make sure your program does what you expect it to do.